# Remove already deleted line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

The following code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Files.Cotacao);
Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[2];
Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

{
    for (int i = 2; i < range.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        var data = new Cotacao
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Descricao = range.Cells[i, 10] != null && range.Cells[i, 10].Value2 != null
                ? range.Cells[i, 10].Value2.ToString()
                : "--",
            ProdutoId = range.Cells[i, 1] != null && range.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null
                ? Select.Produto(range.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString())
                : 4642
        };

        db.Cotacoes.Add(data);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Had a wrongly typed line:

```
Apelido = range.Cells[i, 10] != null && range.Cells[i, 10].Value2 != null
  ? range.Cells[i, 10].Value2.ToString()
  : "--",
```

Which was removed as can be seen.

Despite this removal, I get an error message during the `SaveChanges` telling that the column name `Apelido` is invalid:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Apelido'

How can I get rid of this `Apelido` since it's not even there?

Comment: Is that column referenced in your database context class? Or in the class definition for `Cotacao`?

Comment: What is your deployment? IIS? May be you need to purge temp internet files?

Comment: That Apelido column doesn't exist in the database... Was totally misplaced.
I'm using IIS Express....

Comment: Tough that's a console application... It doesn't use IIS

Comment: If you use IIS - immediately stop using Excel Interop. doing this - `new Excel.Application();` on web server is very bad practice. what you should do instead, use `microsoft.ace.oledb` provider to work with Excel. Now. Again. You removed the line from a source file. But where is the guarantee that code executing is in fact derived from that source?

Comment: I'm not using IIS but thanks for the advice>
I start the debugger and that's the only code available... It can't be another.

Comment: May be your problem is simple - you removed the line but this action has not removed property `Apelido` from the model. Your DB has no such column but property is there on the model. Hence you have this issue. Find model class `Cotacao` and remove `Apelido` there